# Get xml node by attribute value and de-serialize that node

Tags: c#, xml, xml-declaration

I have two XML file as shown below

Format 1:

```
<Template Type="Print">
  <PrintWidth>7</PrintWidth>
  <PrintHeight>5</PrintHeight>
</Template>
```

Format 2:

```
<Templates>
  <Template Type="Print">
    <PrintWidth>7</PrintWidth>
    <PrintHeight>5</PrintHeight>
  </Template>
  <Template Type="Print">
    <PrintWidth>7</PrintWidth>
    <PrintHeight>5</PrintHeight>
  </Template>
</Templates>
```

I have created Mapping Class for the Format 1 as below:

```
public class Template 
 {             
        private double _printWidth;        
        private double _printHeight;         

        /// <summary>
        /// Print width in inches
        /// </summary>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public double PrintWidth {
            get {
                return this._printWidth;
            }
            set {
                this._printWidth = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("PrintWidth");
            }
        }                

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public double PrintHeight {
            get {
                return this._printHeight;
            }
            set {
                this._printHeight = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("PrintHeight");
            }
        }        
}
```

I wanted to desirealize only single node of XML in Format 2 that is having `Type="Print"` into `Template` class. Is there any generic way with which I can deserialize both XML Files (Foarmat 1 and a single node of Format 2)   to `Template` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that can be done by combining [Linq to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) with [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

1. Load the XML into an [`XDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
2. Use linq to find an appropriate element with the appropriate attribute in the XML element hierarchy.
3. Deserialize the selected element, using [`XElement.CreateReader()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.createreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to pass an [`XmlReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that reads the element and its descendants to the serializer.

Thus, for instance:

```
    public static void Test()
    {
        string xml1 = @"<Template Type=""Print"">
          <PrintWidth>7</PrintWidth>
          <PrintHeight>5</PrintHeight>
        </Template>";

        string xml2 = @"<Templates>
          <Template Type=""Print"">
            <PrintWidth>7</PrintWidth>
            <PrintHeight>5</PrintHeight>
          </Template>
          <Template Type=""Print"">
            <PrintWidth>7</PrintWidth>
            <PrintHeight>5</PrintHeight>
          </Template>
        </Templates>";

        var template1 = ExtractTemplate(xml1);

        var template2 = ExtractTemplate(xml2);

        Debug.Assert(template1 != null && template2 != null
            && template1.PrintWidth == template2.PrintWidth
            && template1.PrintWidth == 7
            && template1.PrintHeight == template2.PrintHeight
            && template1.PrintHeight == 5); // No assert
    }

    public static Template ExtractTemplate(string xml)
    {
        // Load the XML into an XDocument
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

        // Find the first element named "Template" with attribute "Type" that has value "Print".
        var element = doc.Descendants("Template").Where(e => e.Attributes("Type").Any(a => a.Value == "Print")).FirstOrDefault();

        // Deserialize it to the Template class
        var template = (element == null ? null : element.Deserialize<Template>());

        return template;
    }
```

Using the extension method:

```
public static class XObjectExtensions
{
    public static T Deserialize<T>(this XContainer element)
    {
        return element.Deserialize<T>(new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)));
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(this XContainer element, XmlSerializer serializer)
    {
        using (var reader = element.CreateReader())
        {
            object result = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            if (result is T)
                return (T)result;
        }
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Incidentally, your `Template` class has a bug: you need to mark `PrintWidth` and `PrintHeight` with `[XmlElement]` rather than `[XmlAttribute]` to deserialize that XML properly:

```
public class Template
{
    private double _printWidth;
    private double _printHeight;

    /// <summary>
    /// Print width in inches
    /// </summary>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute()]
    public double PrintWidth
    {
        get
        {
            return this._printWidth;
        }
        set
        {
            this._printWidth = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("PrintWidth");
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute()]
    public double PrintHeight
    {
        get
        {
            return this._printHeight;
        }
        set
        {
            this._printHeight = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("PrintHeight");
        }
    }
}
```